# ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' when using Hibernate and MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, primary-key

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getTestSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(test1);
    session.save(test2);
    session.save(test3);
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    WARN: SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
ERROR: Duplicate entry '9900001' for key 'PRIMARY'
WARNING: #{RmaBean.send}: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '9900001' for key 'PRIMARY'
javax.faces.FacesException: #{RmaBean.send}: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '9900001' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
```

So, when trying to insert test1 to db I always get that exception. Before inserting that test1 I populate its PK fetching the last PK from DB and adding +1 into it. Is Hibernate somehow keeping in memory that pk and I shouldn't use insert but update?

UPDATE: `

```
<class name="test1" table="test1" catalog="testing">
    <id name="testPK" type="long">
        <column name="testPK" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>`
```

This code was implemented by another person and I just checked from db that there is no Auto Increment true. Assigned means that I have to provide the PK and I am trying to do it.

```
public Integer getLastPK {


    Session session = HibernateUtil.getTestSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Integer pk = null;
    try{

    session.beginTransaction();


    pk = new Integer(session.createSQLQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() from testing.test1").uniqueResult().toString());  
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    System.out.println("1.....pk----------->"+pk);

    if(pk != null && pk <= 9900001){
        System.out.println("IF...");
        pk=9900001;

    }else if(pk != null && pk > 9900001){

        pk = pk+1;
    }
```

UPDATE2: I changed the pk to Auto Increment:

ALTER TABLE `testing`.`test1` AUTO_INCREMENT = 9900001 , CHANGE COLUMN `testPK` `testPK` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  ;

Is this good idea or not? I changed hbm.xml file as well...

Thanks for helping!
Sami

Comment: Can you provide hbm file for test class

Comment: show code, how test1,test2,test3 objects are created with there primary key

Answer (score 1):

How about using `session.saveOrUpdate(test1)` instead of `session.save(test1);`?

saveOrUpdate(Object object) is

> Either save(Object) or update(Object) the given instance, depending
>   upon resolution of the unsaved-value checks.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html

Comment: -1?? I tried that and I got: WARN: SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
ERROR: Duplicate entry '9900001-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
WARNING: #{RmaBean.lahetaLahetys}: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '9900001-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
javax.faces.FacesException: #{RmaBean.lahetaLahetys}: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '9900001-1' for key 'PRIMARY' I'll update my question with code where I am fetching the PK...

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean that :) I meant 9900001-1. Strange exception.

Comment: Can't solve the issue if two thread insert the same record into a table.